WSL tries to link libraries from windows when using cmake
I have installed CentOS 7 for WSL and tried to compile curlpp to use it in one of my projects. However when I try to build the library it tells me
/mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcurl.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized

C/msys64 ... is the path on windows to a curl library, which would explain, why it cannot recognize the file format.
So my question is, why it tries to link with windows libraries and how to make it stop doing that.
Output of make VERBOSE=1
make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 -B/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeFiles /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
make -f CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
cd /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1 /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
make -f CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
Linking CXX shared library libcurlpp.so
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC    -shared -Wl,-soname,libcurlpp.so.1 -o libcurlpp.so.1.0.0 CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Exception.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/internal/OptionSetter.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/internal/CurlHandle.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/internal/SList.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/internal/OptionList.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Easy.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Options.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/OptionBase.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Form.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Info.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/cURLpp.cpp.o CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/src/curlpp/Multi.cpp.o /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcurl.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libcurlpp.so.1.0.0] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/curlpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2

output of cmake .
[root@BF100649 curlpp-0.8.1]# cmake .
-- curlpp version=[0.8.1]
-- curlpp version num=[000801]
-- Looking for CURL
-- Found CURL version: 7.29.0
-- Using CURL include dir(s): /usr/include
-- Using CURL lib(s): /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcurl.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1

output of cmake . -trace
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageMessage.cmake(36):  if(NOT ${pkg}_FIND_QUIETLY )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageMessage.cmake(37):  string(REGEX REPLACE [\n]  details ${details} )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageMessage.cmake(38):  set(DETAILS_VAR FIND_PACKAGE_MESSAGE_DETAILS_${pkg} )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageMessage.cmake(39):  if(NOT ${details} STREQUAL ${${DETAILS_VAR}} )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake(321):  set(${_FOUND_VAR} ${${_FOUND_VAR}} PARENT_SCOPE )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindCURL.cmake(58):  if(CURL_FOUND )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindCURL.cmake(59):  set(CURL_LIBRARIES ${CURL_LIBRARY} )
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindCURL.cmake(60):  set(CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR} )
/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeLists.txt(62):  if(CURL_FOUND )
/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeLists.txt(63):  message(STATUS Found CURL version: ${CURL_VERSION_STRING} )
/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeLists.txt(64):  message(STATUS Using CURL include dir(s): ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeLists.txt(65):  message(STATUS Using CURL lib(s): ${CURL_LIBRARIES} )
/home/user/Projects/curlpp-0.8.1/CMakeLists.txt(71):  include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
-- Using CURL lib(s): /mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/lib/libcurl.a

Solution:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25241
If the wsl.conf file is not there, you can just add it and write:
[interop]
enabled=false
appendWindowsPath=false

After i restarted wsl it worked

Because the curlpp CMake file decided that that was the proper curl library to use. Can you show us the CMake invocation as well as its output? It should tell you which library it found.

I added the cmake command and you are right, cmake is trying to use that library. Do you have any idea on how to fix that ?

Seems like FindCURL.cmake tries (in order): 1) CMake config (curl-config.cmake) 2) pkg-config (libcurl-x.pc) 3) find_library, which looks in $PATH, among others. 4) curl-config. You should re-run CMake with --trace to see which path it took to end up in windows-land.

@Botje: Since find_library is implemented in CMake internally, the option --trace has a little value when debug its search paths. Instead, use --debug-find option.

@Tsyvarev if it goes into that path something is off the rails, given that a standard fedora libcurl-devel package ships with both a pkg-config package and curl-config, which should both point to the system libcurl and not something else.

@Tsyvarev cmake --debug-find . gives me the same output as doing it without. I have added the output of --trace to the post

I just noticed the dreaded "CentOS 7" in the question body .. which version of CMake is this? And do you have a libcurl.pc installed from your libcurl-devel package? (You can check with pkg-config --libs libcurl)

The option --debug-find will print something useful if find_library actually searches for the library, not uses the cached value. Clear the build directory and run cmake --debug-find <path/to/source/dir>.

BTW, by running cmake . you are using in-source build. This is discouraged. Remove CMakeCache.txt file from the source directory, create build subdirectory, and run cmake --debug-find .. from it.

@Botje I have tried it with 2.8.12.2 and then installed cmake3 via yum which is version 3.17.5. pkg-config --libs libcurl only gives me "-lcurl" as output

@Tsyvarev after deleting the cache and creating a build directory , cmake --debug-find .. still gives me the same output as without it, when running it from the build directory

The line numbers in your trace correspond to cmake 2.8.12.2's version of findcurl, which is ancient and only supports approach 3 in my comment above. Please try again with cmake 3.17.5. (you may have to specify the version explicitly somehow)

Ok, I think I found the problem in this Post: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25241
TL:DR I told WSL to stop append the windows path and it worked, thanks for your help.
